# fddi network controller required driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

On a Windows XP machine and at the control panel > system > device manager i have come across a device "FDDI Network interface" that keeps asking for drivers...What's more is that NIC's (onboard and a PCI) that were previously present (along with the underlying connections) are now missing....

Attempt to restore to a previous restore point had no result whatsoever...

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like unplugging the PCI network card and rebooting will solve this problem...have seen it before and this kind  of approach worked. Hope that it does the same for you.